# HTML5/JS Slider Range Bar: Only allow click events, no touchdown/mousedown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the slider bar from HTML5 using bootstrap css/js.

Especially the mobile view has a lot of control elements, so it requires scrolling up/down. This also works quite well. Unfortunately the slider bar triggers when scrolling so the slider changes value.

With buttons etc. this is easy with scrolling, if not clicked a button usually does not trigger.

Can this behavior also be implemented for slider bars? Otherwise, with each scroll operation with the finger, the slider accidentally assumes a new value.

**This is the code for the Slider bar:**

```
<label for="customRange-1" class="form-label">[LABEL]</label>
<input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="10" id="customrange-1">
```

**To catch changes I use this JavaScript:**

```
$('input[type=range]').on('input', function () { 
// some actions
)};
```

**I tried to disable touchdown events:**

```
$('input[type=range]').on('touchdown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But the problem is that the value can't be changed anymore. I only want to allow 'click' similar 'touch' events, but **no touchdown-hold events used for scrolling a page**.

Has anyone an idea?